# Does any hotel in Jaipur allow guests to cook food themselves

Tags: india, food-and-drink, hotels

Some hotels allow guest to cook their own food at extra charge.

A friend of mine is planning to travel to Jaipur (in Rajasthan, India). He could not find a hotel which provides facilities for a guest to cook food himself/herself (due to medical reason).

Does someone know about any such hotel in Jaipur?

Comment: Try Zostel Jaipur!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend should try [Om Nivas Suite](http://Om%20Nivas%20Suite), Jaipur. They say they have a fully equipped kitchen as part of their facilities and [this link](https://www.airbnb.de/rooms/9516783) from airbnb also says so.

Comment: But in any case, it is best to confirm it before booking. You can find their contact details on the first link.